# Search and compare values of a .CSV file

Tags: csv, autoit

My goal is to search a CSV's first column twice, then execute an action (dependent of a value in the third column of same record). I began in VBScript using `InStr()` :

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
roster = "C:\bin\roster.csv"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(roster)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    intLength = Len(strLine)
    intZeros = 5 - intLength

If InStr(strLine, strIP)> 0 Then
    strinfo = split(strLine, ",")
    siteNumA = strinfo (0)
    siteNumB = string(5 - Len(siteNumA), "0") & siteNumA
    siteIP = strinfo (1)
    siteDist = strinfo (2)
    siteReg = strinfo (3)
End If
```

It could compare values of `siteDist` to same data from a second search. However, I prefer to use AutoIt. Is there a way to achieve this using AutoIt (or a command to achieve my plan)?

A simple CSV file I am using for testing :

```
Site,District,Region
1,1,1
2,1,1
3,1,2
4,2,2
5,2,1
```

Searching two separate entries for `Site` and confirming that `District` matches afterwards, running this script at site 1 should have it evaluate as true for `Site` 1, 2, or 3, and false for `Site` 4 and 5.

Comment: You should also include you .csv file so we can test. Else we will be shooting in the dark. It is possible in AutoIT

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name...........: _ParseCSV
; Description ...: Reads a CSV-file
; Syntax.........: _ParseCSV($sFile, $sDelimiters=',', $sQuote='"', $iFormat=0)
; Parameters ....: $sFile       - File to read or string to parse
;                  $sDelimiters - [optional] Fieldseparators of CSV, mulitple are allowed (default: ,;)
;                  $sQuote      - [optional] Character to quote strings (default: ")
;                  $iFormat     - [optional] Encoding of the file (default: 0):
;                  |-1     - No file, plain data given
;                  |0 or 1 - automatic (ASCII)
;                  |2      - Unicode UTF16 Little Endian reading
;                  |3      - Unicode UTF16 Big Endian reading
;                  |4 or 5 - Unicode UTF8 reading
; Return values .: Success - 2D-Array with CSV data (0-based)
;                  Failure - 0, sets @error to:
;                  |1 - could not open file
;                  |2 - error on parsing data
;                  |3 - wrong format chosen
; Author ........: ProgAndy
; Modified.......:
; Remarks .......:
; Related .......: _WriteCSV
; Link ..........:
; Example .......:
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _ParseCSV($sFile, $sDelimiters=',;', $sQuote='"', $iFormat=0)
    Local Static $aEncoding[6] = [0, 0, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    If $iFormat < -1 Or $iFormat > 6 Then
        Return SetError(3,0,0)
    ElseIf $iFormat > -1 Then
        Local $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, $aEncoding[$iFormat]), $sLine, $aTemp, $aCSV[1], $iReserved, $iCount
        If @error Then Return SetError(1,@error,0)
        $sFile = FileRead($hFile)
        FileClose($hFile)
    EndIf
    If $sDelimiters = "" Or IsKeyword($sDelimiters) Then $sDelimiters = ',;'
    If $sQuote = "" Or IsKeyword($sQuote) Then $sQuote = '"'
    $sQuote = StringLeft($sQuote, 1)
    Local $srDelimiters = StringRegExpReplace($sDelimiters, '[\\\^\-\[\]]', '\\\0')
    Local $srQuote = StringRegExpReplace($sQuote, '[\\\^\-\[\]]', '\\\0')
    Local $sPattern = StringReplace(StringReplace('(?m)(?:^|[,])\h*(["](?:[^"]|["]{2})*["]|[^,\r\n]*)(\v+)?',',', $srDelimiters, 0, 1),'"', $srQuote, 0, 1)
    Local $aREgex = StringRegExp($sFile, $sPattern, 3)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2,@error,0)
    $sFile = '' ; save memory
    Local $iBound = UBound($aREgex), $iIndex=0, $iSubBound = 1, $iSub = 0
    Local $aResult[$iBound][$iSubBound]
    For $i = 0 To $iBound-1
        Select
            Case StringLen($aREgex[$i])<3 And StringInStr(@CRLF, $aREgex[$i])
                $iIndex += 1
                $iSub = 0
                ContinueLoop
            Case StringLeft(StringStripWS($aREgex[$i], 1),1)=$sQuote
                $aREgex[$i] = StringStripWS($aREgex[$i], 3)
                $aResult[$iIndex][$iSub] = StringReplace(StringMid($aREgex[$i], 2, StringLen($aREgex[$i])-2), $sQuote&$sQuote, $sQuote, 0, 1)
            Case Else
                $aResult[$iIndex][$iSub] = $aREgex[$i]
        EndSelect
        $aREgex[$i]=0 ; save memory
        $iSub += 1
        If $iSub = $iSubBound Then
            $iSubBound += 1
            ReDim $aResult[$iBound][$iSubBound]
        EndIf
    Next
    If $iIndex = 0 Then $iIndex=1
    ReDim $aResult[$iIndex][$iSubBound]
    Return $aResult
EndFunc

; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name...........: _WriteCSV
; Description ...: Writes a CSV-file
; Syntax.........: _WriteCSV($sFile, Const ByRef $aData, $sDelimiter, $sQuote, $iFormat=0)
; Parameters ....: $sFile      - Destination file
;                  $aData      - [Const ByRef] 0-based 2D-Array with data
;                  $sDelimiter - [optional] Fieldseparator (default: ,)
;                  $sQuote     - [optional] Quote character (default: ")
;                  $iFormat    - [optional] character encoding of file (default: 0)
;                  |0 or 1 - ASCII writing
;                  |2      - Unicode UTF16 Little Endian writing (with BOM)
;                  |3      - Unicode UTF16 Big Endian writing (with BOM)
;                  |4      - Unicode UTF8 writing (with BOM)
;                  |5      - Unicode UTF8 writing (without BOM)
; Return values .: Success - True
;                  Failure - 0, sets @error to:
;                  |1 - No valid 2D-Array
;                  |2 - Could not open file
; Author ........: ProgAndy
; Modified.......:
; Remarks .......:
; Related .......: _ParseCSV
; Link ..........:
; Example .......:
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _WriteCSV($sFile, Const ByRef $aData, $sDelimiter=',', $sQuote='"', $iFormat=0)
    Local Static $aEncoding[6] = [2, 2, 34, 66, 130, 258]
    If $sDelimiter = "" Or IsKeyword($sDelimiter) Then $sDelimiter = ','
    If $sQuote = "" Or IsKeyword($sQuote) Then $sQuote = '"'
    Local $iBound = UBound($aData, 1), $iSubBound = UBound($aData, 2)
    If Not $iSubBound Then Return SetError(2,0,0)
    Local $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, $aEncoding[$iFormat])
    If @error Then Return SetError(2,@error,0)
    For $i = 0 To $iBound-1
        For $j = 0 To $iSubBound-1
            FileWrite($hFile, $sQuote & StringReplace($aData[$i][$j], $sQuote, $sQuote&$sQuote, 0, 1) & $sQuote)
            If $j < $iSubBound-1 Then FileWrite($hFile, $sDelimiter)
        Next
        FileWrite($hFile, @CRLF)
    Next
    FileClose($hFile)
    Return True
EndFunc

; === EXAMPLE ===================================================
;~  #include<Array.au3>
;~  $aResult = _ParseCSV(@ScriptDir & '\test.csv', "\", '$', 4)
;~  _ArrayDisplay($aResult)
;~  _WriteCSV(@ScriptDir & '\written.csv', $aResult, ',', '"', 5)
; ===============================================================
```

or this:

```
#region    ;************ Includes ************
#include <Array.au3>
#endregion    ;************ Includes ************
; _csvTo2DArray

Local $re = _csvTo2DArray("c:\Repository.csv", ';')
_ArrayDisplay($re)

Func _csvTo2DArray($file, $delim = ',')
    Local $content = FileRead($file)
    Local $rows_A = StringSplit(StringStripCR($content), @LF, 2)
    StringReplace($rows_A[0], $delim, $delim)
    Local $countColumns = @extended
    Local $columns_A = 0

    Local $2D_A[UBound($rows_A)][$countColumns + 1]

    For $z = 0 To UBound($rows_A) - 1
        $columns_A = StringSplit($rows_A[$z], $delim, 2)
        For $y = 0 To UBound($columns_A) - 1
            $2D_A[$z][$y] = $columns_A[$y]
        Next
    Next
    Return $2D_A
EndFunc   ;==>_csvTo2DArray
```

and then compare the cells with normal Stringfunctions or use the _Array functions on the array.

Comment: I can get the data into an array using _FileReadToArray, but from there all of the various _Array queries return positional information instead of the value.  If I search for site 1 in the example above, it comes back and tells me that it is found in Row 2, Column 1.  I cannot get it to return any of the other data values from the row.  (Continued in next Comment)

Comment: I was looking at trying to use that then to search a second time based on the discovered row, but once again I hit the same wall - all it would bring back is Row 2, Column 2 - not the data (1) contained therein.  That's where I'm stuck.  I can't find a query in AutoIT that will do what VBS did and give me the DATA from the found line, not just the index information.

Comment: Where is the problem? If you've got the index then no problem to get the value. Just use: $arrayName[row][cloumn] and print it out with consolewrite or MsgBox or use it in your compare statement ...

Answer (score -1):

> … is there another way to achieve my end goal in AutoIT, or is there a direct equivalent command set to what is outlined above to achieve my original plan?

Example using [`_ArraySearch()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArraySearch.htm) (replace `ConsoleWrite()` by whatever action required) :

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global Enum  $CSV_COL_SITE, _
             $CSV_COL_DISTRICT, _
             $CSV_COL_REGION

Global Const $g_sFileCSV   = 'C:\bin\roster.csv'
Global Const $g_sFileDelim = ','
Global Const $g_iColSearch = $CSV_COL_DISTRICT
Global Const $g_sValSearch = '1'
Global Const $g_sMessage   = 'Matched row #%i : %s\n'

Global       $g_iRow       = 0
Global       $g_aCSV

_FileReadToArray($g_sFileCSV, $g_aCSV, $FRTA_NOCOUNT, $g_sFileDelim)

While True

    $g_iRow = _ArraySearch($g_aCSV, $g_sValSearch, ($g_iRow ? $g_iRow + 1 : $g_iRow), 0, 0, 0, 1, $g_iColSearch, False)
    If @error Then ExitLoop

    ConsoleWrite(StringFormat($g_sMessage, $g_iRow, _ArrayToString($g_aCSV, $g_sFileDelim, $g_iRow, $g_iRow, '')))

WEnd
```

Console output (row number +1 for presence of header record):

```
Matched row #2 : 1,1,1
Matched row #3 : 2,1,1
Matched row #4 : 3,1,2
```